# Sling webapp installation deploy error

Tags: sling

I'm trying to run sling framework.

After building it from sources I have `org.apache.sling.launchpad-7-SNAPSHOT.war` file.

When I'm deploying it in tomcat7 I'm getting

> SEVERE: sling: Failed installing jndi:/localhost/sling/WEB-INF/resources/org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/sling/_sling  /Loader_tmp_1397075933316org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar (Permission denied)
>   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)

Have you any suggestions how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `Loader_tmp_` pattern in the problematic file makes me think this happens in the Sling [Loader class](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/base/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/base/shared/Loader.java) when it tries to create a temporary file there. I'd check whether the tomcat process has read/write access to the /var/lib/tomcat7/sling folder.